# Allocation minimum cost with quantity constraint in Python

Tags: python, cost-based-optimizer

I'm trying to solve an allocation problem:

- I have 350 000 parcels with size S_i, each parcel can only have a state, and for each parcel I have a set of probability
- for each state, I have a quantity to reach

I found the Vogel approximation method but with 350 000 rows (parcels) and 15 columns (possible states), the computation time should be too long.

Do you know minimum-cost allocation algorithms that could solve this kind of problem ?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the cost problem that you're trying to solve, and perhaps provide some of your code + sample inputs/outputs? As it is, it is very difficult to understand your problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to describe the problem more clearly. What is the "state" of a parcel, what does "a quantity to reach" mean? You can give a smaller example where you show the input, the output, and an explanation for why that output is correct.

Comment: I want to thank Enthus3d and kaya3. I discussed with a computer scientist colleague and according to him, this way to go should not suit with the constraints of my problem.